# Azure set up availability test of internal url

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have a public web app on which I can set up an availability test from Azure. I also have a private web app on which the availability test fails.

I want to track the availability of my internal web app. In C#, I have found until now:

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "application insights key";
var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
var avail = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.AvailabilityTelemetry();
telemetryClient.TrackAvailability(avail);
```

However this code is unfinished. I'm not sure how I would specify my internal url and where I would see the results.

Comment: For monitor an internal url, you should read this [Can I monitor an intranet web server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/troubleshoot-faq#can-i-monitor-an-intranet-web-server) first.

Comment: @IvanYang Just to be sure, does that article also include a web app that is on Azure but has a private url (on which the basic availability test fails)?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no. But you can raise an issue for that in that article -> Feedback section.

Comment: @IvanYang Then I'm sorry I wasn't clear, my private web app is in Azure, and that's where I want to do an availability test.

Comment: can you just use the code your have in the private web app, then check the telemetry in portal?

Comment: @IvanYang Yes, it worked after around 5 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

For the internal web, first of all, you should make sure "allow traffic to our services by either firewall exceptions or proxy redirects.", detail is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/troubleshoot-faq#can-i-monitor-an-intranet-web-server).

Then just a simple line of code, just define some specific properties or name for your internal url in AvailabilityTelemetry.

```
            var client = new TelemetryClient();
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "xxxxx";
            AvailabilityTelemetry a = new AvailabilityTelemetry();
            a.Name = "this is your_web_site_name or other unique value";

            //or some properties like below
            //a.Properties.Add("p1", "my internal web");

            client.TrackAvailability(a);
```

Then after execution, you can check if the availability telemetry is in azure portal -> your application insights service:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately it doesn't work after all with putting the website url for a.Name. a.Name is just the name of the test...If I put a.Name = "Test" it will show up "Test" in application insights after 5 minutes. Should have seen it earlier.

Comment: There are always some delay for messages being shown in application insights. The telemetry data will be batched first, then sent to application insights.

Comment: No but I mean that it doesn't actually monitor the website url, it will just show up in the portal whatever value you give for a.Name in your code. If you give a.Name = "dgaagd" then it will show 100% availability on "dgaagd", to give an example.

Comment: Another issue that I found here is if the function app is down/stopped, this 'availability test' will not work.